# How can I make an accurate user-agent string in python?

Tags: python, testing, user-agent, wsgi

I want to test a wsgi application. I want to make an accurate `environ` variable without making any socket connections or http calls. (If my test framework is the server, and the app lives on the same machine, why make http calls?)

I found [webtest](https://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and am currently looking at it's source to figure it out (it's not working for google app engine apps for some reason).

My current issue with making an accurate environ variable is the user-agent. I can get system information with `import platform; platform.uname()`, but it returns `Darwin` for Macbooks and not `Macintosh`, which is found in a `user-agent` string when sent from a macbook. I've found multiple libraries to generate 'fake' user-agents, but I want to make the *real* one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "accurate" and "real" user-agent. Do you want to emulate what a particular browser might generate? If so, which browser?

Comment: [Am I missing something obvious?](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)

Comment: @jDo now call that but from python, and without an http get request. Basically, what is the user-agent of a python script?

Comment: *"Basically, what is the user-agent of a python script?"* It depends on the module, python version and the OS. E.g. `import requests; print requests.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/").text` returns "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic" here if I don't change anything manually. That did involve a request though. It's set [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/f0860bd3ca396bef15f194a449736ae3ac4f4812/requests/utils.py#L588), I believe

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google App Engine, and the issue is having an accurate user agent *from within a test*, first thing is you'll probably want to use [App Engine Testbed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting). From there there are special instructions on [using webtest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting). Unless you're doing something weird, that should work just fine.

The way then to pass custom headers, including user agent, is like this ([per the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/testapp.html#making-requests)):

```
app.get('/path', [params], [headers], [extra_environ], ...)
```

So for example:

```
app.get('/foo', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```